# Make 3D plot from matrix

Tags: r, 3d, density-plot

I have a `2D matrix`:

```
cells                  Rpl37a    Itm2c   Atp1b1     Olfm1      Prnp   
1: AAACGGGCAATCTACG-1 1.7876878 2.393453 4.527764 2.0751658 2.3934526 
2: AAGTCTGCAGCGAACA-1 1.9235754 1.683439 4.034793 1.6834394 1.9235754 
3: ACAGCCGAGTACGTTC-1 1.7168081 2.422601 4.021788 2.0605259 2.0605259 
4: ACATCAGCAGGTTTCA-1 3.1849476 2.165849 4.139574 0.0000000 1.8161277 
5: ACCCACTAGTGTACCT-1 0.8960067 2.018112 4.774355 2.0181116 1.3608743 
6: ACCTTTAAGTGGTCCC-1 3.2418217 1.199632 3.185896 1.7294919 0.8718525 
7: ACGATACCAAGAAGAG-1 1.2513362 2.396079 3.977721 1.2513362 2.9158808 
8: ACGGGCTGTACAGTGG-1 3.5215001 1.710004 2.824437 2.0532873 2.5993292
```

For each column I need to produce a density plot that shows the distribution of the row-values, and then show all of the density plots on one `3D` chart. How could I achieve that? I know there is `plotly` library, but I am completely new and having trouble with it.

> Update

My goal is to see all of the distributions at the same time somehow. I do not know how to achieve that. Just `2D` superimposed line charts would not work because the matrix above I just showed as a sample to try, in reality it has much more rows and columns. I may need not only density plots, but also just line chart for each column.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(yourdataset)` so that we can use the same data.

Comment: A plof like this one .? https://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-density-plot-in-r-with-plotly/

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not show the dataset with `dput` because it is too big, and copy-pasting exceeds the number of allowed characters in `stackoverflow`

Comment: I do not know though how to supply the `2D` matrix values that I have into `plot_ly` function. I tried to access their `density_plot.txt.` but it is unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this, but I'm not convinced.

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000*10), ncol=10))
names(dat) <- LETTERS[1:10]

xvalues <- apply(dat, 2, function(y) density(y)$x)
xmin <- min(xvalues)
xmax <- max(xvalues)
yvalues <- c(apply(dat, 1, function(a) density(a, from=xmin, to=xmax)$y))
dd <- cbind(c(yvalues), xvalues=c(xvalues), a = colnames(dat))

library(plotly)
plot_ly(data.frame(dd), x = ~xvalues, y = ~a, z = ~yvalues, split = ~a, 
        type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")
```

[image]

## EDIT

Better but still not convincing.

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(150*10), ncol=10))
names(dat) <- LETTERS[1:10]

xvalues <- apply(dat, 2, function(y) density(y)$x)
xmin <- min(xvalues)
xmax <- max(xvalues)
yvalues <- c(apply(dat, 2, function(a) density(a, from=xmin, to=xmax)$y))

dd <- cbind(c(yvalues), xvalues=c(xvalues), a = colnames(dat))

library(plotly)

plot_ly(data.frame(dd), x = ~xvalues, y = ~a, z = ~yvalues, split = ~a, 
        type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines")
```

[image]